# BeautifulSoup: How to include the encoding on output?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to include the encoding tag in an XML document using `BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup`, but I'm not sure how!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mytag>stuff</mytag>
```

It outputs the encoding tag when I read a document that already has it, but I'm making a new soup.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I'll give an example of what I'm currently doing.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup, Tag
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup()
mytag = Tag(soup, 'mytag')
soup.append(mytag)

str(soup)
# '<mytag></mytag>'

soup.prettify() # No encoding given
# '<mytag>\n</mytag>'

soup.prettify(encoding='UTF-8')
# '<mytag>\n</mytag>' # Where's the encoding?
```

Even if I create the soup like `BeautifulStoneSoup(fromEncoding='UTF-8')`, there is still no `<?xml?>` tag.

Is there another way to get that tag without creating and passing the tag as a string directly, or is that the only way?

Comment: Beautiful Soup isn't meant to be an XML *generator*.  The prettify method is just for convenience.  Why don't you use lxml directly?

Comment: @Zack: Partly because almost all of the XML usage I perform is parsing, so BeautifulSoup sounded like a good idea to use; and partly because all of the building methods are already set up for use with BeautifulSoup, so rewriting them doesn't sound appealing. I will definitely remember to try lxml next time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>')
# make some more soup
```

Or,

```
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup()
# make some more soup
soup.insert(0, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>')
```

---

From the BeautifulSoup [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit):

> Beautiful Soup tries the following encodings, in order of priority, to turn your document into Unicode:
>
> - An encoding you pass in as the fromEncoding argument to the soup constructor.
> - An encoding discovered in the document itself: for instance, in an XML declaration or (for HTML documents) an http-equiv META tag. If Beautiful Soup finds this kind of encoding within the document, it parses the document again from the beginning and gives the new encoding a try. The only exception is if you explicitly specified an encoding, and that encoding actually worked: then it will ignore any encoding it finds in the document.
> - An encoding sniffed by looking at the first few bytes of the file. If an encoding is detected at this stage, it will be one of the UTF-* encodings, EBCDIC, or ASCII.
> - An encoding sniffed by the chardet library, if you have it installed.
> - UTF-8
> - Windows-1252
>
> Beautiful Soup will almost always guess right if it can make a guess at all. But for documents with no declarations and in strange encodings, it will often not be able to guess.

N.B. item #2, which I read as: BeautifulSoup will use the encoding in the xml declaration automatically, if you don't explicitly specify one with the fromEncoding argument. YMMV.

There are other, potentially useful, unicode related examples in the earlier referenced [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit), as well.

---

**Edit**: @TorelTwiddler, if there is another way to add an xml declaration using BeautifulSoup without passing the tag as a string directly, I am not aware of it.

That said, consider the following:

```
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup('<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?>') # <- no encoding
mytag = Tag(soup, 'mytag')
soup.append(mytag)

print str(soup)
# "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><mytag></mytag>" 
# Wha!? :)
print soup.prettify(encoding='euc-jp')
# <?xml version='1.0' encoding='euc-jp'?>
# <mytag>
# </mytag>
```

Perhaps that'll help you get where you want to go.

Comment: So then I need to specifically insert the formatted tag? It doesn't figure it out based on the encoding I give it anywhere?

Comment: @TorelTwiddler I'm not sure I follow your question. Are you already 'giving' the encoding? Or wondering where to 'give' it?

Comment: I've updated the question with more information, and hopefully a more direct answer to what I was looking for.